# Android doesn't create folder on my Nexus

Tags: android, file

I have a **Nexus** 9 device. I would create a personal folder in the /sdcard/ path, something like this:

```
/sdcard/MyFolder/
```

so i coded this:

```
File directory = new File("/sdcard/MyFolder/");
    if(directory.mkdirs()){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Folder created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Folder not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

When I launch the app, it shows me "Folder not created" and so it doesn't create folder called MyFolder into /sdcard/ path. In Nexus 9 device the `/storage/emulated/0`path doesn't exist, so I have to use /sdcard/ path to accessing my storage.

I also used permission in my AndroidManifest.xml file, in this way:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Can you tell me please what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: In addition, since a Nexus 9 should be running Android 6.0+, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you need to handle the permission at runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission

Answer (score 4):

Since lots of devices have different file structures it is safer to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for determining the SD card path.

Can you try this code

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder");
if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdir();
}
```

Comment: just tried but still doesn't work..in my storage doesn't appear folder i would create

Comment: nope it doesn't show me any errors. It seems works perfectly but doesn't create any folder. I think it's a nexus device problem

Answer (score 0):

try to specify external storage as listed below:

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/MyFolder");
```